# Optional question mark - regexp

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have problem with creating correct regular expression.
Here is what I have so far:
https://regex101.com/r/d0epRo/2

I need to add to this links one more parameter and I have to determinate wheather there is question mark or not. Therefore `?` should be optional but I can't get it to work.

Those not working `(\?|)` `(\?)?` `(\??)`.

Those should be marked `http://www.polskieszlaki.pl` and `http://www.polskieszlaki.pl/wawel.htm` but aren't

I have no forther ideas. Help please.

Comment: Why not use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (with DOMXPath perhaps)?

Comment: I guess it's slower

Comment: At least you would understand what you are doing. Your regex is a mess, and is not doing what you think it is. Please add the real requirements to the question.

Comment: Obligatory: [**Don't parse HTML with regex**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610)

Comment: Also, note that `[^mailto]` is not doing what you think it is. It is saying "One letter that is not `m`, `a`, `i`, `l`, `t` or `o`". (The description on the right of your link tells you this!) A better approach would be to use `https?`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you want is this regex:

```
a[\s]+href="[^mailto][\S]+polskieszlaki\.pl(?:(.*))?(?:(\?)(.*))?\"
```

This (?: ... ) means "do not capture"

Answer (score -1):

If you are just trying to retrieve the query parameters try:

```
a[\s]+href="[^mailto][\S]+polskieszlaki\.pl(.*)(?:\?(?<param>.*))\"
```

You can then extract the `param` group

Or in a more simpler form without the named + ignored capture groups:

```
a[\s]+href="[^mailto][\S]+polskieszlaki\.pl(.*)(\?(.*))\"
```